# Thread safety for high-performance in-memory cache

Tags: c#, performance, thread-safety, micro-optimization

I have a static in-memory cache that is written to only once an hour (*or longer*), and **read by many threads at an extremely high rate**. Conventional wisdom suggests I follow a pattern such as the following:

```
public static class MyCache
{
    private static IDictionary<int, string> _cache;
    private static ReaderWriterLockSlim _sharedLock;

    static MyCache()
    {
        _cache = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        _sharedLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    }

    public static string GetData(int key)
    {
        _sharedLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            string returnValue;
            _cache.TryGetValue(key, out returnValue);
            return returnValue;
        }
        finally
        {
            _sharedLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    public static void AddData(int key, string data)
    {
        _sharedLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            if (!_cache.ContainsKey(key))
                _cache.Add(key, data);
        }
        finally
        {
            _sharedLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

As an excercise in micro-optimization, how can I shave off even more ticks in the relative expense of shared **read** locks? Time to **write** can be expensive, since it rarely happens. I need to make reads as fast as possible. Can I just drop the **read** locks (below) and remain thread-safe in this scenario? Or is there a **lock-free** version I can use? I'm familiar with memory-fencing but don't know how to safely apply it in this instance.

Note: I'm not tied to either pattern so any suggestions are welcome as long as the end result is faster and in C# 4.x.*

```
public static class MyCache2
{
    private static IDictionary<int, string> _cache;
    private static object _fullLock;

    static MyCache2()
    {
        _cache = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        _fullLock = new object();
    }

    public static string GetData(int key)
    {
        //Note: There is no locking here... Is that ok?
        string returnValue;
        _cache.TryGetValue(key, out returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    public static void AddData(int key, string data)
    {
        lock (_fullLock)
        {
            if (!_cache.ContainsKey(key))
                _cache.Add(key, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For micro-optimizations like this you really have to profile first. How many % do the ReaderLocks take up now?

Comment: Your second version isn't thread safe. There is nothing guarding a read while you are writing.

Comment: How MUCH performance on the write side are you ready to sacrifice for read performance ? You can make a non-lock version that simply replaces the dictionary whenever it needs to add data. No locks for reads, but obviously, _a lot_ slower in the write scenario.

Comment: driis... will the full lock on writes not prevent reads while the full lock is in place?

Comment: driis, writes can be much much slower. For the no-lock scenario could you provide a couple lines to show what the GetData method might look like? I am just not sure how many memory barriers I need and where to place them.

Comment: @JoeGeeky, how could it? The code in `GetData()` doesn't know anything about the lock, so it won't react to it in any way.

Comment: Henk, that is a good question. I have profiled it but don't have the figures handy at the moment. By my memory, the shared read locks are costing around 10-20 nono-seconds per read.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need a lock when there are threads only ever reading from the data structure. So, since writes are so rare (and, I assume, not concurrent), an option might be to make a full copy of the dictionary, make the modifications to the copy, and then atomically exchange the old dictionary with the new one:

```
public static class MyCache2
{
    private static IDictionary<int, string> _cache;

    static MyCache2()
    {
        _cache = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    }

    public static string GetData(int key)
    {
        string returnValue;
        _cache.TryGetValue(key, out returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    public static void AddData(int key, string data)
    {
        IDictionary<int, string> clone = Clone(_cache);
        if (!clone.ContainsKey(key))
            clone.Add(key, data);
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _cache, clone);
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on some other comments above, the GetData() method would not be thread-safe in this case. Consequently, I'd be back to using some kind of locking mechanism. This is not a bad idea, but it would seem that it doesn't address read performance issues.

Comment: GetData would not be thread-safe if there is a thread manipulating the dictionary referenced by `_cache`. But there is no thread manipulating it, so it *is* thread-safe!

Comment: That was my original thought but previous comments seem to disagree. In any case, I'm trying to test this now. Thanks.

Comment: The GetData method in your second example is not thread-safe because AddData is manipulating the dictionary referenced by _cache.

Comment: I assume this is only safe if I can guarentee that no two threads ever try to AddData() at the same time, otherwise, one update might get lost. In my case, that's not an issue, I just wanted to make sure I understood this.

Comment: After a wide range of tests, this pattern out-performed everything I tested with one exception. The Hashtable approach Marc suggested consistently beat this for speed when reading in short bursts (details in my comment on his post). In this case, I needed sustained performance for both small and large caches, so this one is the winner. Also, the ConcurrentDictionary performed VERY closely to this one. If I wasn't trying to squeeze out every last tick, this could be a good option too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

I would be looking to go lock free here, and achieve thread safety by simply **not changing any published dictionary**. What I mean is: when you need to add data, create a complete copy of the dictionary, and append/update/etc the **copy**. Since this is once an hour this shouldn't be a problem even for large data. Then, when you have made the changes, simply swap the reference from the old dictionary to the new dictionary (reference reads/writes are guaranteed to be atomic).

One caveat: any code that needs consistent state between **multiple** operations should capture the dictionary into a variable first, I.e.

```
var snapshot = someField;
// multiple reads on snapshot
```

This ensures that any related logic is all made using the same *version* of the data, to avoid confusion when the reference swaps during the operation.

I would also take a lock **when writing** (not when reading) to ensure no squabbling over the data. There are lock-free multi-writer approaches too (primarily Interlocked.CompareExchange and reapply if it fails), but I would use the simplest approach first, and a single writer is exactly that.

Comment: In regards to capturing the variable to maintain consistency between operations. Does that apply to consistency within an if condition e.x. `if(someField == null || someField.SomeProp == null)` is it possible for `someField` to change between conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative option: the .net 1.x Hashtable (essentially Dictionary, minus the generics) has an interesting threading story; the reads are thread safe without locks - you only need to use locks to ensure ***at most*** one writer.

So: you might consider using a non-generic Hashtable, no locking on reads, and then take a lock during writes.

This is the main reason I still find myself using Hashtable sometimes, even in .net 4.x applications.

One problem though - it'll cause the int key to be boxed for both storage and query.

Comment: Intersting, I didn't know this... I'm adding this to the test list, which at this point is getting lengthy :-). But boxing??? Ouch!

Comment: @joe yes - most times the key is a string, so that isn't an issue. But the per-query boxing would be GEN-0 collectible, so probably not a big problem actually.

Comment: The tests are in... The Hashtable performed very well. In short bursts (e.g. <1 minute on my hardware) it out performed everything I tested for high-performance read under high rates of concurrency. This included a no-lock dictionary, concurrent dictionary, etc... However, under sustained loads it fell behind the no-lock dictionary approach suggested by dtd. There was a curious tick in the metrics that occured at a regular interval which caused its long-runner performance to drop slightly. All things considered not a bad option for some scenarios.

Comment: @Joe I wonder if that tick is collection of the boxed imt values?

Comment: One other benefit for this approach is the lack of the key not found exception being thrown. Since I don't have to worry about the exception no try-catch is required. This means that methods containing the call will still be eligible for inlining JIT optimizations. :-)

Comment: @Joe you can avoid those using the Try* methods, for example `if(data.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {...}`

Comment: Yeah I know, I used the Try* on all my tests where its supported. As you can imagine there is a little more IL behind those calls, so x = y[z] is slightly leaner.

Comment: When I test ConcurrentDictionary vs Hashtable with a lock around writes, ConcurrentDictionary wins every time. Granted this is 8 years later...so perhaps things have changed in .net 4.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

This makes a copy of the dictionary only when data is being added. A lock is used for adding but you can take that out if you don't intend to add from more than one thread. If there's no copy then data is pulled from the original dictionary, otherwise the copy is used while adding.

Just in case the copy gets nulled out after it's checked and seen as not null but before it's able to retrieve the value, I added a try catch which in that rare event, it will pull the data from the original which is then locked but again, this should happen very rarely if at all.

```
public static class MyCache2
{
    private static IDictionary<int, string> _cache;
    private static IDictionary<int, string> _cacheClone;
    private static Object _lock;

    static MyCache2()
    {
        _cache = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        _lock = new Object();
    }

    public static string GetData(int key)
    {
        string returnValue;
        if (_cacheClone == null)
        {
            _cache.TryGetValue(key, out returnValue);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                _cacheClone.TryGetValue(key, out returnValue);
            }
            catch
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    _cache.TryGetValue(key, out returnValue);
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    public static void AddData(int key, string data)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _cacheClone = Clone(_cache);
            if (!_cache.ContainsKey(key))
                _cache.Add(key, data);
            _cacheClone = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at lock free data structures.  http://www.boyet.com/Articles/LockfreeStack.html is a good example

Comment: This was a very interesting read... well written too. In this case, these are all Sequential access structures which don't suite the case I presented above. With that said, I'm spinning up a performance rig now because I'm curious how well his lock-free queue implementation performs against the built-in .NET version. :-)

Comment: As promised, I tested the lock-free queue implementation. Unfortunetally in every test case the lock-free version is slower then using the generic Queue with a full lock. The full lock queue was 2 times faster in almost every case. I like the idea, but the numbers tell the story.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the lock-free queue you led me to was faster then Microsofts ConcurrentQueue when working with small numbers of items. As the size of the queue grew the lock-free queue fell behind and the ConcurrentQueue became faster. For small queues go ahead and use the Generic queue with full locks... its much faster in that case.